# How to list out nodes of all partitions in gephi using java?

Tags: java, modularity, gephi

I have imported ".gdf" file for the graph. Using "force atlas 2" and "modularity" I have already partitioned the graph with colouring. Now I want a list of nodes (Their IDs) for every partition which were created. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that when you use modularity a new attribute is added to the AttributeModel. That attribute is the ModularityClass.
You can easily retrieve the modularity class of each node by doing:

```
Node[] nodos=directedGraph.getNodes().toArray();
    for(Node n:nodos){
        System.out.println(n.getId()+" "+n.getAttributes().getValue(Modularity.MODULARITY_CLASS));
    }
```

Hope it helps!